# SQL group-by on column (Value) for only those rows having duplicates in other column (Count(ID) >1)

Tags: sql, group-by

I have an Table similar to this which would be **Input for SQL**

```
    ID                     Value
    FRY6040501ACH19        1388
    FRY6040501ACH19        1389
    FRY6040501ACH19        1388
    <Null>                 13800
    <Null>                 13800
    <Null>                 <Null>
    0026003710022745       1388
    0026003710022752       <Null>
    0026003710022751       32750
    0026003710022751       32750
    0026003710022751       32750
```

I need to write an SQL to get the output with additional `Status` Column.

I am adding intermediate columns `TmpCntID` & `TmpCntVl` to explain the logic

The **required Output from SQL** is as below: (`TmpCntID` & `TmpCntVl` not required)

```
    ID               TmpCntID     Value    TmpCntVl   Status
    FRY6040501ACH19      3        1388       2        MisMatch
    FRY6040501ACH19      3        1389       1        MisMatch
    FRY6040501ACH19      3        1388       2        MisMatch
    <Null>               3        13800      2        MisMatch
    <Null>               3        13800      2        MisMatch
    <Null>               3        <Null>     1        MisMatch
    0026003710022745     1        1388       1        NA
    0026003710022752     1        <Null>     1        NA
    0026003710022751     3        32750      3        Match
    0026003710022751     3        32750      3        Match
    0026003710022751     3        32750      3        Match
```

The Logic used here is first find ID's having repetition using `SELECT ID, Count(*) FROM MyTable M GROUP BY IIF(IsNull(ID), '0', ID), ID having COUNT(*)>1` to get the  **Intermediate Output** as:

```
    NDUPID            TmpCntID
    FRY6040501ACH19      3
    <Null>               3
    0026003710022751     3
```

Now, for a moment, we need to ignore the rest of the ID's like `0026003710022745` or `0026003710022752`

From first table above for each `ID` which is in `NDUPID (above intermediate output)` find for non-duplicate `values`. Any one non-duplicate must indicate all the rows with same `ID` to be `Mismatch`

For Example against `ID=0026003710022751`, we can see all the three `values=32750` and hence `Status=Match` and for `ID=FRY6040501ACH19` and `ID=<Null>` we have at least one duplicate `value` hence it is `Status=Mismatch`

And in output table above for all the rows having `TmpCntID=1` , we need to have `Status=NA`

Logic in mind is to calculate `TmpCntVl` and `TmpCntID` first however not needed in final output, then using case statement if both columns are equal then **`Match`** if both columns are not equal then **`MisMatch`** and for all the `ID`'s that are not in  **Intermediate Output** Table above, that is `count(*)<=1` the status would be **`NA`**

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something but it looks like you want your `Status` column definition to be:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TmpCntID = 1 THEN 'NA'
     WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM interTbl tt 
                 WHERE tt.ID = tbl.ID AND tt.TmpCntVl = 1)
          THEN 'MisMatch'
     ELSE 'Match'
END AS Status
FROM interTbl tbl
```

That is,

- `NA` when unique
- `MisMatch` when any `TmpCntVl` for that `ID` is 1
- `Match` otherwise

---

I misunderstood the question in that you knew how to get the intermediate output and did not know how to proceed from there. Here's what I would do:

```
WITH Counts AS
(
    SELECT ID, Count(*) AS TmpCntID
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY ID
),
LoneValues AS
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY ID, Value
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT myTable.ID, myTable.Value,
    CASE WHEN Counts.TmpCntID = 1 THEN 'NA'
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM LoneValues WHERE myTable.ID = LoneValues.ID
                           OR (myTable.ID IS NULL AND LoneValues.ID IS NULL))
              THEN 'MisMatch'
         ELSE 'Match'
    END AS Status
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN Counts ON myTable.ID = Counts.ID 
    OR (myTable.ID IS NULL AND Counts.ID IS NULL)
```

I don't guarantee this is the *most optimal* solution, so if it becomes a problem later then you can think about how to fix it.

I have also [tried this query on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4a1a/3) so you can see it in action. If your RDBMS does not support CTEs you can of course just paste them in as subqueries where necessary.

Comment: Yes but I need to get `TmpCntVl` and `TmpCntID`. I am facing difficulties to get `TmpCntVl` form `Input for SQL` Table

Comment: Logic in mind is to calculate `TmpCntVl` and `TmpCntID` first, then case it to find if both columns are equal then `Match` if both columns are not equal then `MisMatch`

Comment: Let me try something similar to <b>`group by ID, Value` left outer join `group by ID` on ID</b> But Still not clear...

Comment: `group by ID, Value left outer join group by ID on ID` should hopefully fetch me `TmpCntVl` and `TmpCntID` and then I can use `Case` Statement... ?

Comment: But Handling `<Nulls>` is a big challenge.. :(

Comment: Sry `group by ID` left outer join `group by ID, Value` on `ID`? Can u please help me on this.... Plz plz plz....